# Using Form Inside Antd Modal

Tags: reactjs, antd

**ERRORCODE:**

```
index.js:1 Warning: Instance created by `useForm` is not connected to any Form element. Forget to pass `form` prop?
```

I am using React with Antd and I open a modal on a button click, the button passes some data which I am capturing via "e" and render them onto the modal.
The problem is whenever the modal is closed and opened again, the contents inside do not re render, it uses the previous event data. I've figured it is because I am not using the Form properly.
I will post the code below please let me know where I have gone wrong.

```
    import react, antd ...etc

function App () => {
  const sendeventdata(e) => {
const EventContent = () => (
      <div>
        <Form
          form={form}
          labelAlign="left"
          layout="vertical"
          initialValues={{
            datePicker: moment(event.start),
            timeRangePicker: [moment(event.start), moment(event.end)],
          }}
        >
          <Form.Item name="datePicker" label={l.availability.date}>
            <DatePicker className="w-100" format={preferredDateFormat} onChange={setValueDate} />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="timeRangePicker" label={l.availability.StartToEnd}>
            <TimePicker.RangePicker className="w-100" format="HH:mm" />
          </Form.Item>
          <span className="d-flex justify-content-end">
            <Button
              className="ml-1 mr-1"
              onClick={() => {
                form
                  .validateFields()
                  .then((values) => {
                    onUpdate(values)
                    form.resetFields()
                  })
                  .catch((info) => {
                    console.log('Validate Failed:', info)
                  })
              }}
            >
              {l.availability.updateBtn}
            </Button>
            <Button danger className="ml-1 mr-1" onClick={() => handleDelete()}>
              Delete
            </Button>
          </span>
        </Form>
      </div>
    )
}
  const MyModal = () => {
    const { title, visible, content } = e
    return (
      <Modal
        onCancel={handleModalClose}
        title={title}
        visible={visible}
        footer={null}
        form={form}
        destroyOnClose
      >
        {content}
      </Modal>
    )
  }
return <div><MyModal /><Button onClick{sendeventdata}></Button></div>
}
```